# Ubuntu 21.04 on my desktop with Nvidia 2080Ti GPU no Wayland?

Tags: nvidia, 21.04, wayland

I cant figure out how to enable wayland on my desktop PC, I remember when I first installed ubuntu 21.04 Wayland was active, but now its showing X11. I would like to use wayland to profit from the trackpad gestures.
Any idea how to "revert" back to wayland ?

So far I tried:

`/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` the line to turn off wayland is commented out.

`RUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nvidia-drm.modeset=1"` added this line to  `/etc/default/grub` and ran update-grub.

installed this package: `libnvidia-egl-wayland1`

my GPU driver is propertary nvidia driver 470.86

still when im in the login screen I only have 2 options namely: Ubuntu or Ubuntu xfce, no signs of wayland.

Comment: You meant "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nvidia-drm.modeset=1"", yes?

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 1):

Nvidia 470.94 is supposed to, with modifications, allow **limited*** use of Wayland instead of X11/xorg. I don't personally think that Nvidia and Wayland are ready for prime time yet. Without modifications, Nvidia will force the use of X11/xorg.

*ie: Nvidia-settings won't work properly when running Wayland.

See https://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/495.46/README/xwayland.html

See https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2021/debian-ubuntu-linux-mint-nvidia-guide/4/

See https://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/495.46/README/index.html

Confirm that Secure Boot is disabled in your BIOS.

To change to using Wayland, log out of your session, and at the login screen, select your username, then click on the icon in the lower-right side of your screen, and select "Ubuntu" or "Ubuntu on Wayland". If you don't see this icon, or these choices, then Nvidia is still forcing X11/xorg, and you need to recheck your Wayland modifications.

You can check "Settings/About" to see which Windowing System you're currently running.